# Querying data for current day and only the most recent entry

Tags: sql, informix

I'm new to Informix and am trying to figure out some of the syntax.  I have a table that stores agent status information.  I only want to pull two things from the table;

1 - The current day's rows

2 - Only the most recent entry for each agent

So, a query of

```
select limit 5 agentid, eventdatetime from agentstatedetail order by eventdatetime desc
```

will yield;

```
+------------+------------------------+
| agentid    | eventdatetime          |
+------------+------------------------+
| 1552       | 2013-12-04 16:48:20.122|
| 1482       | 2013-12-04 16:48:18.897|
| 1439       | 2013-12-04 16:48:17.754|
| 1188       | 2013-12-04 16:48:15.972|
| 788        | 2013-12-04 16:48:15.190|
+------------+------------------------+
```

The Informix syntax seems a bit different from mysql.  How can I pull this kind of information?  I tried using the "today" modifier, but it doesn't work the way I thought it would.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could get the max eventdatetime for each agentid that has a row for today with:

```
SELECT agentid,max(eventdatetime)
FROM agentstatedetail 
WHERE date(eventdatetime) = TODAY
GROUP BY agentid;
```

p.s. To get the same effect of `LIMIT 5` in informix you do `SELECT FIRST 5` ...

Comment: This is fine but in the case the query return more fields from agentstatedetail, it will not work.

Comment: I'm not really following your train of thought. What part do you think would not work?

Comment: For example, we need return agentName in agentstatedetail table.

Comment: That would be true but that is not in the question. This is the most efficient way of doing what was asked. I think you are over thinking it.

Comment: Not exactly over thinking. I just wanted a solution in the case the query return other fields too. Is it better?

Comment: That's perfectly fine.

Comment: I will upvote the comments in this thread because they all make valid points.  However, Filipe's solution (in my mind, anyway) is more straightforward and understandable.  My question is; if I take Filipe's solution and decide to not group by agentid but rather order by the most recent transactions, I get an syntax error.  In my mind, I should be able to say; SELECT agentid, max(eventdatetime) FROM agentstatedetail WHERE date(eventdatetime) = TODAY order by eventdatetime desc .  But if I use the GROUP BY, it works fine.  Shouldn't this work?

Comment: @Kimomaru. Nop. Whenever you select some column and then an aggregate functions like MAX you have to GROUP by, that other column/columns, otherwise you get an error. But you can add ORDER BY MAX(eventdatetime) DESC at the end  of my query (after the GROUP BY) if you want the results sorted by that column

Comment: Ahhh, interesting!  Thank you, kind sir.  Much appreciated :)

Comment: Filipe - one more question?  When I add one more column (which I will like use to further filter results), I get an error.  SELECT agentid, max(eventdatetime), eventtype FROM agentstatedetail WHERE date(eventdatetime) = TODAY GROUP BY agentid order by max(eventdatetime) desc .  Any ideas?

Comment: @Kimomaru. That can get a little tricky. Do you want to get one max(date) for every combination of agentid,eventtype (Just add eventtype to the group by), or you just want to add the eventtype to the results that my earlier query gives you (a little trickier)?

Comment: Yes, I would like to just have the eventtype added to the output.  The eventtype tells me if the agent is logged in, ready to take a call, not ready, etc.  It does it with number codes.  So, I'm doing this for a wallboard and I will eventually need to not only do this, but also join the query to another table to pull the resource name, then also find which team they are in, etc.  For now, though, if I can append the eventtype that would be great.  Informix is a bit odd compared with mysql I think.

Answer (score 1):

Hope this work:

```
select A.agentid, A.eventdatetime 
from agentstatedetail A
where 
date(A.eventdatetime) = TODAY
and A.eventdatetime = ( select MAX(B.eventdatetime) from agentstatedetail B where A.agentid = B.agentid)
```